# groovyldap, search only returning 5000 results

Tags: groovy, ldap

I am doing an LDAP search with groovyldap, the search returns the group that I am looking for but only returns 5000 members of the group:

```
def getGroupMembers() {
    def ldap = LDAP.newInstance(connectionInformation.hostname, connectionInformation.user, connectionInformation.password)
    def result = connection.search("CN=mygroup", "OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=blech", SearchScope.SUB)
    def members = result["member;range=0-4999"]
    members = members[0]
}
```

Yes, there is actually a field returned with the key "member;range=0-4999", and the "members" array has 5000 elements in it. I couldn't find any setting in the LDAP code to enable returning all members, but it seems logical to think that I should be able to fetch all of the results.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Active Directory implements [LDAP policies](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20policy%20in%20Active%20Directory) are implemented using objects of the queryPolicy class.

Appears the one which you are encountering is the [MaxValRange](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MaxValRange) which the number of values that are returned in the retrieval of multi-valued attributes of an entry.

In Microsoft Active Directory 2008 (and I assume later, this is hardcoded and although it can be modified, it is not effective).

If an attribute has more than the number of values that are specified by the MaxValRange value, from LDAP, you may use [LDAP_SERVER_RANGE_OPTION_OID](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_SERVER_RANGE_OPTION_OID) "Control" to retrieve values that exceed the MaxValRange value.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what is happening. The solution seems rather complicated, and I have not yet figured out how to do it in Groovy/Grails.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible answers for you. (Sorry, it's been a while since I've played with LDAP / ActiveDirectory).

1. You may be hitting AD page size limits. [Learn more about page size limits](http://jeftek.com/219/avoid-changing-the-maxpagesize-ldap-query-policy/), and the easiest way here is to implement paging in your ldap queries.

How exactly to do that in groovyldap is (unfortunately an exercise for the reader, but I've done it with nodeldap. I think it emits a `page` event(?) it's been a while since I've done this.

2. You may have a range query. I don't know much about these, but there's some thoughts on that in [another StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074903/224334).